# How to open third party url in new window from UIWebView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

I open my mobile site in UIWebView but I want that links to another sites opens in new window in Safari. So I have code like that:

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {

    NSLog(@"*** %@", request.URL.absoluteString);

    if (![self checkURL:request.URL]) {    
        //open external links in Safari
        if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:request.URL])
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:request.URL];
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)checkURL:(NSURL *)url {

    NSURLComponents *urlComp = [NSURLComponents componentsWithURL:url resolvingAgainstBaseURL:YES];

    if ([urlComp.host rangeOfString:@"myprojectsite.ru"].length > 0 ||
        [urlComp.host isEqualToString:@"connect.mail.ru"] ||      //for MailRu registration
        [urlComp.host isEqualToString:@"js.stripe.com"]) {        //prevents opening this link by Safari

        return YES;
    }

    return NO;
}
```

Everything works great but on my site I have javascripts from stripe and it downloads script `https://js.stripe.com/v2/channel.html?stripe_xdm_e=` with content-type `text/html` and due to it this script opens in new window. I have made hack in `checkURL` method. But what if I'll have new scripts like from Stripe. I try to check `navigationType` but for this link it returns UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked. How can I figure out of this problem?

Answer (score -1):

There is one delegate method of UIWebview "shouldStartLoadWithRequest" which has a parameter Request. From this request we can easily fetch the URL which it is going to open. Then once you have the url you can present modal one UIViewcontroller which will have one UIWebview in it and will load that url. Then from cancel button we can make a dismiss call to this view controller when we are done with it.
Hope this may help.